# Using Sockets to Connect to other machine in Python

Tags: python, sockets

So I spent 4 hours in disgrace trying my best to make this happen ->

I have been trying to learn Socket and I played with server-client code a bit on the same computer, and it was working fine, but then I got interested in trying to connect my laptop which is connected on the same WIFI... so what I was trying to do was, run the server code on my PC and client code on my laptop.

Server Side Code

```py
import socket

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
port = 9999
serversocket.bind(('', port))
serversocket.listen(5)

i = 1

while i < 2:
   clientsocket, addr = serversocket.accept()
   print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))
   msg = "Thank you for connecting to %s" % str('') + "\n"
   clientsocket.send(msg.encode('ascii'))
   clientsocket.close()
   i += 1
```

Client-Side Code

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = "127.0.0.1"

port = 9999

s2 = socket.create_connection((host, port))
#s.connect((host, port))

msg = s2.recv(1024)

s.close()
print(msg.decode('ascii'))
```

All the things that I have tried

1. Tried changing to Server IP Address in `host` in client code
2. Tried a lot of ports
3. Tried "0.0.0.0" `host` at server side
4. Turned down all firewalls on server and client-side

Comment: How are the two machines networked together?  If they're both talking to the same WiFi router, it may have a "client isolation" feature turned on that prevents any direct communication between them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Sockets: how to connect between two computers on the same wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294848/python-sockets-how-to-connect-between-two-computers-on-the-same-wifi)

Comment: On the server, get its current IP address and then use that on the client machine.

Comment: How computers find each other on the network can be challenging. Sometimes DNS knows the right names and you can just use the server's host name in a `socket.gethostbyname()` call on the client. Other times, other naming services like mDNS have to be used.

Comment: @PM77-1 no it doesnt, it sounds like the same question, but It does not help me, I have tried that too

Comment: @tdelaney I have tried that , it didn't work

Comment: @tdelaney i have tried using the hostname, it didn't work again

Answer (score 0):

Your client is connecting to 127.0.0.1 which is localhost.

Your Server IP address has a different IP than your laptop IP address.

Therefore, it shouldn't be able to connect since your client has nothing listening to port 9999 on it's localhost.

Try getting the server's IP address and using that instead.

Comment: I have tried that too, I have tried IPv4 address from `ipconfig` in windows and also public IP address from [link](https://whatsmyip.org) , but still it didn't work